# edit configuration of NDK_builder

Tags: android, android-ndk, builder

I have two NDK project in my eclipse, and I want to configure NDK_builder for them.

I've finished the configure for the first project, by [Project->Properties->Builders->New] step and edit the configuration. The builder name is NDK_builder.

Anyway, when I try to apply this procedure to my second project, in the edit configuration step, when I try to name my builder 'NDK_builder', here comes the error: ' A 'Program' configuration with this name already exists'.

So, should I change the builder's name for this project? And the builders' name of each project are not the same? That is quite unconvinient.

Could anyone help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Same error, had to create a second builder.

I just appended the project name like so: "NDK Builder for [project name]".

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bug Report for that error - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365232

> Martin Larente CLA Friend 2011-11-30 13:42:36 EST
>
> It seems that Eclipse is unable to create an external builder that has the same name of another project's external builder, even though the corresponding launch configuration is saved in the project folder.

This is the answer:

> Michael Rennie CLA Friend 2011-11-30 16:23:13 EST
>
> This is because launch configurations have a flat naming scheme. See also bug 59289. This bug has been marked as a duplicate of bug 59289

Also see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=59289 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400126